# embed youtube video parameters ignored

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pattern-matching, embed

I use the following code to replace youtube urls to embed links in order to display them as videos. But I have come to a problem where I can't view videos from links having more parameters other than ?v=video_code

php code:

```
function embedYoutube($text)
{

    $pattern = '|http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?.*?\bv=([^ ]+)|';
    $replacement = '<div style="width:100%;float:left;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;"><iframe width="570" height="315" src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your regex to match only the `v` parameter, and before the first `&`:

```
|http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?.*?\bv=([^ ]+)\&?|
```

Comment: what if there are no "&" in the url? meining just /watch?v=abcd

Comment: with your new pattern if i use http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Vo_F_2eWMw&feature=g-all-u it wont work returning "An error has occured. bla bla bla" but if i use http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Vo_F_2eWMw it will work fine...